# Cannot create telephony manager log found

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I was using firebase to run a robo test and found this:

> cannot create TelephonyManager from ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, [****], UserHandle{0}
>
> process id: 1634 (VvmPkgInstalledRcvr...)

Is this somehow important to initiating an activity?

Comment: Did you find any solution? @Joshua Lee

Comment: @Joshua Lee- Have you find any workaround/solution

Comment: hello? any solution? I am stuck